# How to automatically count number of lines printed by each command?

Tags: bash, shell, wc

How to automatically count number of lines printed by each command?

Examples:

```
$ echo xxx
xxx
1

$ ls -1
xxx
yyy
zzz
3

$ > t0.txt
0

etc.
```

I.e. how to correctly add `| wc -l` into `.bashrc`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Perhaps if you can explain why you're looking for this, sometime may be able to provide a more direct solution to the underlying requirement

Comment: @roaima It is simple: I frequently count the number of lines printed by a command via `| wc -l`. So I am thinking to automate it.

Comment: Counting output is fairly straightforward in the specific case, sure. But remember what you're asking isn't simply to add `| wc -l` to everything because you want to see the output too. I'm responding to your "how do I do this automatically for everything". I don't think it's possible

Comment: @roaima Re: "I don't think it's possible": can you elaborate? What exactly makes you to think so? What are the obstacles? Can the impossibility (if so) be formally proven?

Comment: I'm stating an opinion qualified by over 30 years using UNIX style systems. (It doesn't mean I'm right, mind.) I don't believe there is any mechanism, short of reimplementing a shell (possibly in shell script), that allows you to send all cooked output to another command that can then send it on to the terminal and also count the number of lines. You'd have to convince the calling program it was talking to a terminal (contrast `ls` with `ls | cat`) and also know to step aside gracefully if you fired up a full screen editor such as `vi`

Answer (score 0):

Combination of many commands, using Bash:

```bsh
ls -1 \
    | cat <(echo) - \
    | cat -n \
    | tac \
    | cat -n \
    | while read i n line; do
        if [[ $i == 1 ]]; then
            echo $((n - 1))
        fi
        echo $line
    done \
    | tac \
    | tail -n +2
```

Output:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
3
```

- `cat <(echo) -` adds an empty line to the head because if stdin is zero lines, the code block above will not work correctly
- `cat` command with `n` option adds line number to head
- `tac` command reverses stdin
- In `while` loop, print reversed first line number and stdin
- finally, `tac` again and `tail -n +2` to print the expected output
- It works too replace `ls -1` with `echo xxx`, `> t0.txt`, etc.